# Mounting Page Blob as a VHD in a batch file

Tags: mongodb, azure

This is a follow-up to my [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259985/java-access-to-mongodb-server-running-on-windows-azure/10260383#10260383): how do I mount a page blob as a VHD on worker role instance? After the drive is mounted, I will pass that as the value of --dbpath parameter to mongo instance.

In a nutshell, I'm trying to start a single mongo instance with the data directory on azure blob (for durability). I'm building on the [HelloWorld](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh690944%28VS.103%29.aspx) example on Azure's site-- instead of starting Tomcat instance, I will start mongo instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you follow this guide: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/81413/Windows-Azure-Drives-Part-1-Configure-and-Mounting. This guide explains how to mount the drive but it also shows how you can save the drive letter as an environment variable.

This is interesting for when you're starting the mongo instance, you can just use this environment variable together with --dbpath. Maybe it would be best to encapsulate all the code in a console application so that you can simply start it before starting the mongo instance.

Comment: thanks for the link. Is there a Java based solution? Looking for the equivalent of Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudDrive that can be used to mount.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure if you can mount a drive in Java. Currently this feature is not available in Windows Azure Storage Client for Java: https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-java. There’s no native (C++) API either. So you may need to use .NET to mount the drive, and then start your Java process from your .NET application. For now, you can also submit a feature request on http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/34192-windows-azure-feature-voting.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.